# How to open MainActivity from asset file in another activity

Tags: android, html, url, android-activity, assets

I have two activities called:

1. `MainActivity.java`
2. `page1.java`

`page1.java` contains my asset file (`file:///android_asset/index.html`). This is working very well.

Code in `page1.java` contains something like this:

```
engine.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

I want to add an URL in `index.html` file to go to `MainActivity.java`.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index.html add

```
<a href="javascript:Android.launchMain()">MainActivty</a>
```

Now create a new class named ActivityLauncher

```
public class ActivityLauncher {
private Context m_context;

public ActivityLauncher(Context context) {
    m_context = context;
}
@JavascriptInterface
public void launchMain() {
    m_context.startActivity(new Intent((Activity)m_context,
         MainActivity.class));
   }
}
```

Now add this lines in page1.java

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new ActivityLauncher(this), "Android");
```